# Should x._1,x._2... syntax be avoided?

Tags: scala, tuples

I'm just starting out in Scala. I find myself using tuple variables a lot.

For example, here's some code I wrote:

```
/* Count each letter of a string and return in a list sorted by character
 * countLetter("test") = List(('e',1),('s',1),('t',2))
*/
def countLetters(s: String): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  val charsListMap = s.toList.groupBy((c:Char) => c)
  charsListMap.map(x => (x._1, x._2.length)).toList.sortBy(_._1)
}
```

Is this tuple syntax (x._1, x._2 etc) frowned upon by Scala developers?

Comment: I'll think it's okay and desired by the Scala developers. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are the tuple accessors frowned upon by Scala developers?

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer (by one character) answer: yes.

Too many `_n`'s can be a code smell, and in your case the following is much clearer, in my opinion:

```
def countLetters(s: String): List[(Char, Int)] =
  s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).toList.sortBy(_._1)
```

There are lots of methods like `mapValues` that are specifically designed to cut down on the need for the noisy tuple accessors, so if you find yourself writing `_1`, etc., a lot, that probably means you're missing some nice library methods. But occasionally they're the cleanest way to write something (e.g., the final `_1` in my rewrite).

One other thing to note is that excessive use of tuple accessors should be treated as a nudge toward promoting your tuples to case classes. Consider the following:

```
val name = ("Travis", "Brown")

println("Hello, " + name._1)
```

As opposed to:

```
case class Name(first: String, last: String)

val name = Name("Travis", "Brown")

println("Hello, " + name.first)
```

The extra case class definition in the second version buys a lot of readability for a single line of code.

Comment: This is good advice, but I consider `mapValues` and friends a code smell also--more of a library smell than a user-land smell, but still, lots of overly specific methods that need to be remembered and maintained.  I'd rather have remappers on tuple elements: `_.map(_.f2(_.length))`

Comment: @RexKerr: I don't know—having a separate method for `mapValues` clearly captures the idea that `_.map(_.f2(_.length))` is a very different animal from `_.map(_.f1(_.length))` on maps. I'm with the language designers on this one.

Comment: Pleas mention in your answer that `mapValues` is lazy. It reduces memory usage, but evaluates at every access to value.

Comment: @senia: But you'll always need to force it before sorting (e.g., with the `toList` here). I don't think I've ever been bitten by forgetting the laziness of `mapValues`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Uh, I have. It was very nasty; it happened in some GUI code and caused a memory leak. Took me at least a day to find the cause of the leak.

Comment: I like the idea of using case classes instead of tuples (often), but mapValues is really a special case - it's the perfect answer for a `Map`, but that's it (I'm curious about the "tons of methods like `mapValues`).

Comment: I'd like to point out that, while I agree with the answer, I think that the usage `x._1`, `x._2` and similar is very clear for pure, i.e. mathematical usage of tuples. Actually, I event tend to replicate that in Java (since I know Scala).

Answer (score 19):

There is a better solution then `x._N`. Common way to work with tuples is pattern matching:

```
charsListMap.map{case (a, b) => (a, b.length)}
```

You also may take a look at `scalaz`, there are some [instruments](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleBifunctor.scala.html) for tuples:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> (1, "a") bimap (_ + 2, _ + 2)
res0: (Int, java.lang.String) = (3,a2)

scala> ('s, "abc") :-> { _.length }
res1: (Symbol, Int) = ('s,3)
```

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: Not the downvoter, but this doesn't answer the real question, and `mapValues` is more idiomatic, anyway.

Comment: @TravisBrown: There is `mapValues` in your answer and it's the way to do for Map. But pattern matching is more generic solution. It work in almost all cases for tuples.

Comment: @TravisBrown It is worth noting that `mapValues` creates a wrapper around the original map, thus introducing overhead each time you get a value, whereas senia's solution creates a new direct map.

Comment: @senia: That's a fair point, and if your answer had said that, I would have upvoted it.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: I'm not sure that's relevant here (because of the `toList`), especially since the asker is a self-professed beginner and in most cases `mapValues` does exactly the right thing. But you have my blessing if you want to edit my answer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Scala 3`, with the [parameter untupling](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html) feature, the following will become an alternative for `.map(x => x._1 -> x._2.length)`:

```
.map(_ -> _.length)
```

and thus, your example becomes:

```
"test".toList.groupBy(identity).map(_ -> _.length).toList.sortBy(identity)
// List(("e", 1), ("s", 1), ("t", 2))
```

---

Concerning your example more specifically and starting in `Scala 2.13`, you could also use [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html#groupMapReduce%5BK,B%5D(key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,B%5D) which (as its name suggests) is an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a reduce step:

```
"test".groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _).toList.sortBy(identity)
```